# Linq to Entity insert data in db

Tags: c#, database, linq, save, entity

How can I insert data added in GridView after clicking Save buton on BidingNavigator using Linq to Entity.

I am trying to add data to database but some problem occurs. I'm showing data using this code:

...

```
 private void PostojeciPRojekti_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            dbcontext = new logicrms2Entities1();

            var projekti = from c in dbcontext.projekti
                             select c;

            projektiBindingSource.DataSource = projekti.ToList();
            projektiGridControl.Refresh();



        }
```

...

**EDIT**

I have try to save data using:

```
   private void projektiBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        dbcontext.SaveChanges();
        gridView1.RefreshData();


    }
```

Comment: Where is the code for saving data to the database?

Answer (score 1):

First maintain a list of newly added objects in your form:

```
private List<projekti> addedList = new List<projekti>();
```

Then, handle **RowsAdded** event on your DataGridView:

```
dataGridView1.RowsAdded += new DataGridViewRowsAddedEventHandler(dataGridView1_RowsAdded);
```

Next, add any added object to the list in your RowsAdded event handler :

```
private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
     addedList.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem as projekti);
}
```

Finally, in your navigator's save button **click** event handler method you can store the objects:

```
private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var dbcontext = new logicrms2Entities1();
     addedList.ForEach(p=> dbcontext.projeckit.Add(p));
     dbcontext.SaveChanges()
}
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer I will try that. :)

Comment: You are very welcome and please don't forget to mark it as Answer if it is ok.

Comment: Problem:  GridView does not contain a definition for 'RowsAdded' and no extension method 'RowsAdded'

Comment: By GridView do you mean System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView? If so, it has an event called RowsAdded: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx

Comment: My bad...sorry I am using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView